# How can I perform this type of thing? (java)

Tags: java, arrays

I am now studying java and I'm having a lot of issues in this chapter of 1 dimensional arrays.
What I need to do in this question is to detect if , in the array, there are the same amount of numbers above the avarage than below the average. Now, what I dont know, after I detect the middle of the array, how I can calculate the average since I dont know how to add all the numbers together, remember that I cant just say `array[1]+array[2]+array[3]` because I simply dont know how many array elements there are...

Comment: Did you learn about loops?

Comment: Your question title does nothing whatsoever to tell us what your question is about. Some grammar would also help.

Comment: So, it seems like your question is "how do I average an array of ints"?

Comment: can you try rephrasing your question, it's a bit of a mess to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop:

```
double total = 0; //Total of all the numbers in the array
double average; //Average of all the numbers in the array
int belowCount = 0; //Number of numbers below the average
int aboveCount = 0; //Number of numbers above the average
int sameCount = 0; //Number of numbers at the average
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    total += array[i];
}
average = total/array.length;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] < average){
        belowCount++;
    }
    else if (array[i] > average){
        aboveCount++;
    }
    else{
        sameCount++;
    }
}

if(belowCount==aboveCount)
{
    return true;
}
else 
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted to count the numbers above and below the average instead of just getting the total or average of the numbers in the array, so I reflected this in my answer.

Comment: @OP Does this answer your question? There hasn't been any response from you in a few days.